# Inequality with $abc=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $a;b;c$ be positive real numbers and $abc=1$

Find maximum value of: $P=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+2b^2}}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{b^2+2c^2}}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{c^2+2a^2}}$

I tried to use Cauchy-Schwarz: $a^2+2b^2 \geq \dfrac{1}{3}(a+2b)^2$

Then: $P \leq \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{a+2b}+\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{b+2c}+\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{c+2a}$

So, what should I do next? Thank you.

Comment: Is there a maximum ? What happens when $a\to 0^+,b\to 0^+,c\to \infty$?????

Comment: Maybe the condition on $a,b,c$ is different as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2189428/maximize-frac1-sqrt2a2b2-frac1-sqrt2a2c2-frac1-sqrt2c?noredirect=1)?

Comment: @VIVID possible but it is *highly* unlikely that the OP mistook that complex condition to be  $abc=1$ !!

Comment: Maybe you are looking for minimum?

Comment: @lonestudent even in that case we cannot save the question see my answer :)

Comment: Oh, thank you, so it's a incorrect problem. I wil report back to my teacher

Comment: @Albus Yes. We can not. But, we have still chance. Just we need $a+b+c=1$ and $a,b,c>0$ and if we are looking for local minimum. But the question is also changing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no maximum .

Note that when $a\to 0^+,b\to 0^+,c\to \infty$ we get  $P\to \infty$ .This is because the $\sqrt{a^2+2b^2}\to 0$

Note that we chose $c\to \infty$ because $c=\frac{1}{ab}$

---

Now even if you are looking for the minimum there is no minimum .

Note  again that  $a\to 0^+,b\to \infty,c\to \infty$ we see that $P\to 0$.